# Writing to hard disk , whilst running windows defragmenter (secondary hard drive)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, defragment

Is it ok to write to a HDD whilst running the defrag tool? I decided to check how fragmented it was and it was 39% so I am defragging, but its taking a  long time. I wanted to install a game to my Steam library but this is on the same secondary hard disk that Im defragging.

It is taking many hours to defrag and I am wondering if it would hurt the defrag process and/or hard drive for me to install the game there now.

(Its a USB external 1tb hard drive about 3 years old)

Thanks

Comment: <cringe> you really shouldn't. it makes the defragmenters job almost impossible, and in the worst cases, might even result in dataloss in extreme cases. You can probably get away with it, which is why they don't require you to schedule a defrag on a device via exclusive locking as they do with chkdsk, but still...

Comment: ok thanks Frank. I have managed to resist from doing it and have installed it on my tiny SSD for now. Hopefully it will complete before I do sleep lol. (I started it about 3 hours ago and it on 28% so I doubt it haha)

Comment: Some defragging utilities, like Degraggler from Piriform (my preferred defragger), will actually quit and post a message saying there's too much drive activity for it to perform it's job.

Comment: At least in the w9x days, the defragmenter would rebuild the block map any time the disk changed, so it could reevaluate its pending operations.

Comment: sadly guys i had to cancel it at 51% but will just do it tomorrow whilst I am not using the PC. Thanks for your help